# Creating ruled page for stationery

Tags: loops

I'm trying to create a ruled page for stationery using customized line colors, etc. I'm currently using the `memoir` class as the document class. I want lined paper. I can create a single line pretty easily with

```
\rule[-0.15em]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
```

But I'm not sure how to repeat for the entire text block. I'm figuring a `\loop \repeat` checking the current location in the text block against `\textheight` but I'm not sure how to the current offset. Is this a good method? Or is there something better?

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is proposed by [Vafa Khalighi](https://www.ctan.org/author/khalighi) at http://qa.parsilatex.com/24180.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{picture,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    {\color{gray}%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
         -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }%
      }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To use this code with memoir, it is necessary the class option 'oneside', because the lines are positioned with '\oddsidemargin' distance. In twoside with memoir, it is necessary to program the use of '\evensidemargin' on even pages. But for your purpose, the actual code is sufficient.

Comment: I'm using different odd/even margins (this is going into a text signature for binding). I'm having trouble figuring out the correct place to put an \ifodd or similar to handle the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've modified Vafa's answer and have it working now. Here's my complete solution

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{picture,xcolor}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\title{Journal}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\strictpagecheck
\cleartooddpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\cleartooddpage
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    {\color{gray}%
    \checkoddpage\ifoddpage%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
         -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }}%
     \else%
      \put(\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin,
            -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }}%
     \fi%
  }}%
}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[4]
\newpage
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```